# Example for $ S_{4} $-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ S $ be a group. A group $ G $ is called $ S $-free if no quotient group of any subgroup of $ G $ is isomorphic to $ S $. What is the example for a $ S_{4} $-group ?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, shouldn't any group of order less than $24$ work? Or even any abelian group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cameron Williams noted, but one can generalize his argument : using cardinality arguments, *any* group whose cardinality is not divisible by $24$ will work. This is because a quotient of a subgroup of $G$ has cardinality dividing $|G|$, thus if $24$ does not divide $G$, this cannot happen. I guess you can have fun finding lots of finite groups with such order.

Hope that helps,